# Обработка ComboBox в MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть ComboBox который содержит коллекцию `List<string> Folders` которая состоит из путей к папкам, а так же содержит строку "Добавить папку".
Что бы хотелось? Когда пользователь выбирает "Добавить папку" то открывался бы диалог выбора папки, выбранная папка добалялась бы в коллекцию `Folders` и ComboBox отображал бы не "Добавить папку", а соответственно выбранную папку.
В принципе главное у меня работает, но  ComboBox продолжает отображать "Добавить папку" и при выборе не обновляет у себя ComboBoxItemы.
Я понятное дело делаю что-то не так, и прошу подсказать как надо.

Вот код XAML (лишнее я поубирал):

```cs
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" SelectedItem="{Binding Directory}"/>
```

VeiwModel

```cs
private List<string> folders;
public List<string> Folders 
{
     get => folders; 
     set 
     {
           folders = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Folders"); 
     }
}

private string directory;
public string Directory
{
    get { return directory; }
    set
    {
        directory = value;
        if (directory == "Добавить папку")
        {
            directory = chooseFolder(); //Диалог выбора папки
            Folders.Insert(0, Directory);
        }
        // тут кое что будет
        OnPropertyChanged("Directory");
    }
}
```

Как я уже сказал в ComboBox стоит выбранная строка "Добавить папку" и варианты выбора не обновляются (хотя логика програмы дальше работает нормально, именно с той папкой которую выбрали)

Я сначала подумал, что нужно обновить ссылку на `List<string> Folders` что бы всё заработало (да я только учусь, потому не пинайте сильно) и дописал такой код: (на месте комментария `// тут кое что будет`)

```cs
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
temp.AddRange(Folders);
Folders = temp;
```

И тут мой мозг не выдержал :( В итоге имеем: если выбрать строку "Добавить папку", то прга зацикливается и происходит бесконечный вызов диалога выбора папки. Почему так происходит? Обновляю список, а вызов метода происходит будто я обновляю поле `string Directory` ??
И самое главное: как же всё таки правильно прописать?

Comment: наверное вызывать диалог через binding не лучшая идея. почему бы не подвязаться к событию SelectionChange?

Comment: "Добавить папку" это View слой, а значит место всему этому в XAML. По сути у вас 2 варианта (зависит от того, где это "добавить" размещается и сколько их). Если 1 в конце: Узнайте [последний](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131197) элемент коллекции и задайте ему нужный `DataTemplate`, который будет содержать в себе например кнопку с привязанным `Command`. Если объектов несколько и в случайном месте: Сделайте `DataTemplate` с указанием типа, где тип - это ViewModel того или иного объекта, находящемся в `List<object>`. WPF сам подставит тогда нужный дизайн указанному VM объекту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл решение на свой вопрос.
К сожалению это скорее всего убогий костыль, но работает как задумывалось. А как правильно пока останется загадкой :(.
Тем не менее, переписал часть кода и всё заработало как надо.

```
    public string Directory
        {
            get { return directory; }
            set
            {
                directory = value;
                if (directory == "Добавить папку" && ch == true)
                {
                    ch = false;
                    directory = chooseFolder(); //Диалог выбора папки
                    Folders.Insert(0, directory);
                    List<string> temp = new List<string>(folders);
                    Folders = temp;
                    Directory = Folders[0];
                }
                OnPropertyChanged("Directory");
                ch = true;
            }
        }
```